# bash + putty, how to make putty beep?

Tags: bash, putty, beep

I have a bunch of long running scripts on a remote system. quite long running scripts. I'd love to inform the user that all jobs are done with a "beep". In my naive way, I installed the "beep" package, and set PuTTY to play a custom sound, and told the script to "beep -e /dev/pts/0", but, while the sound plays properly, "beep" issues a "ioctl: Inappropriate ioctl for device". What's wrong there?

Yes, I could happily ignore this by redirecting the response to /dev/null, but...?

Cheers,

Carsten

Comment: Can you just do `echo -ne '\007'`?

Comment: Detailed troubleshoot for this topic is at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1145299/unix-windows-putty-bell-or-beep-utility-wont-ring-the-unix-is-ubuntu-server-1)

Comment: The echo thing works. Funny enough that "BEL" still exists ^^

Comment: Just in case a Windows user might read this: after trying the Linux version, I went back to Windows and gave this a try:

echo ^G

And it works! Even in Windows 11. Check! ^^

(Remark: Do not enter ^ and G seperately, just hit CTRL, hold, then press G)